# RTL langauages aren't displayed correctly inside reportlab's tables

Tags: python, arabic, reportlab

I cannot correctly display Arabic text inside a table despite being displayed correctly using `drawCentredString`!!

Here's an example:

```
from arabic_reshaper import reshape
from bidi.algorithm import get_display


def arabic(text):
    return get_display(reshape(text))
```

```
# This works
_canvas.setFont("NotoNaskhArabic-Regular", 24)
_canvas.drawCentredString(x=A4[0] / 2 - 10, y=760, text=arabic("نص عربي"))
```

```
# But this doesn't work
_canvas.setFont("NotoNaskhArabic-Regular", 18)
_head = Table([ [arabic("نص عربي")] ])
_head.wrapOn(_canvas, 0, 0)
_head.drawOn(_canvas, 10, 700)
```

**After rendering**

[image: Python Reportlab Arabic bug]

Comment: I suggested you ask this question on the [reportlab-users] mailing list, https://pairlist2.pair.net/mailman/listinfo/reportlab-users .  The developers hang out there.

Answer (score 0):

You will find an example here:

https://github.com/abduhbm/python-flask-ar-pdf/blob/c76c9be5a9f996fed17ac0e19443ae9f5db022a0/api/endpoints/pdf.py#L43